# WPF EventTrigger for SourceInitialized

Tags: wpf, events, window, mvvm-light

in my window I want to use this code

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SourceInitialized">
        <command:EventToCommand Command="{x:Static wpf:Window.InitializeWindowProcessHookCommand}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

to hook the `SourceInitialized` event to a command on my so-called `Window` class.
I am using MvvMLight [`EventToCommand`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn237302.aspx) and if it works perfectly if I use the `Loaded` event instead of the `SourceInitialized`, so we can assume that the command and further logic is working.
Additionally, using the event with code behind works, but I am looking for a solution using `EventTriggers` (if possible).

When looking up a possible solution, I stumbled across a topic on [MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d5fccb3b-48af-43a3-bd8b-04fc4919d4a5/behaviour-for-windowsourceinitialized-event?forum=wpf), which is about this exact topic, and the OP points states that he successfully bound to the `Loaded` event, but cannot get binding to the `SourceInitialized` to work

> [and I] want to write a similar one for windows source initialized event,  but find that `Window.SourceInitializedEvent` is not exposed

Is there any possible solution to that?

Many thanks in regard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SourceInitialized` event fires before your trigger has a chance to invoke the command so this won't work.

Also, it doesn't make much sense to fire the command using an `EventTrigger` that is defined in the XAML markup just for the sake of not having to do it from the code-behind of the same view. MVVM is not about eliminating view-related code from the views and it doesn't break the pattern to invoke the command from the code-behind of the same view as your XAML markup is defined in.

So invoke the command from an event handler in the code-behind or subscribe to another event.

As you have already noticed, there is no way to handle the `SourceInitialized` event of a window using an `EventTrigger` that is defined in the XAML markup of the same window.